# Sending data to blynk with python to control widget LED

Tags: python, internet, server, communication

Greetings fellow programmers! Yesterday I asked a question on how to install blynk for python3, and thanks to some generous help I got it to install itself. However, now I need to know how to control Widget LEDs on the app through python. As it turns out, no tutorials exist on how to do this. I checked Youtube, The official blynk website, and other reliable sources.  Can anyone here tell me how to do this or at least point me to a tutorial that I might have overlooked?

Comment: Please answer if you can. I really need to finish this project!

Comment: Well, you really need to watch this pretty lady, at least three times. :) Blynk an LED on Raspberry Pi - 49,930 views 2017apr17
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=LJ3ic8C8CcA. Happy watching Cheers.

Comment: And are you sure you want to do it using python on Rpi? Why not cheat by doing everything in the Blynk cloud?

Comment: And two more must watch YTs:(1) https://blynk.io/,
(2) https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=3KFvoDDs0XM. Cheers.

Comment: Nice videos. Sorry, but I was looking for how to control the LED on the Blynk app. Thanks for trying.

Comment: I actually saw that lady before :)

Comment: I have to use python in order to communicate with the program I'm writing.

Comment: Ah let me see. If you want to communicate in both direction, you need to output and input. To blink a LED is to output to GPIO pin. Similarly, to read a push button is to input from GPIO pin. Blynk output Rpi GPIO should be as simple as Blynk input Rpi GPIO. So how should we start, from Google?

Comment: Don't worry about it anymore. I joined the Blynk community and they had the answer. I will post the answer shortly. Thanks for your help.

Comment: You are welcome. It is  like "You can't beat them, join them.", or an "engineering trade off" or "cost benefit analysis". It all depends on your "goal". If my goal is to learn how to write an app, then even if I can get it for free, I would still write the driver myself. Usually I write the driver all by myself, and if I get stuck, I will cheat and peek. If I finally complete the program, I would then compare and contrast mine with others. Often the open source drivers are minimal one scratching surface. The DIY way, beside "Problem Based Learning" make it easy to add bells & whistles. Cheers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well everyone, if you have the same problem I would recommend joining the Blynk community. Their site is a lot like this one to find answers. 
Use these commands to turn it on and off.

```
 #to turn it on
 blynk.virtual_write(10,255)
 # to turn it off
 blynk.virtual_write(10,0)
```

I would not expect immediate results because it takes a few seconds for python to connect to Blynk. So I would run this code in a loop, waiting a few seconds between commands.

Comment: How nice to see the easy solution. I thought it would take me hours to study how to "Virtual Blynk Write LED and Read Button. Cheers.